# Can I set a button in google sheets to alter the image url

Tags: image, validation, google-sheets, checkbox, google-sheets-formula

This feels like it should be dead simple but I've not tried anything like this in google sheets before.

I have an image on a sheet but I want it to change to another image (either via altering the image url, or just hiding one and showing another etc) either via clicking the images themselves or just via a button but have no idea where to start with this and all my googling has ironically, turned up absolutely nothing.

Any help or pointers to useful sources would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, can you clarify how the image is loaded onto the sheet? Are you using `=IMAGE()`? Or did you insert the image directly? (to a cell or over cells?) Also, are you open to using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)?

Comment: I had just imported the image directly via a URL, Im very much open to using any scripting imaginable I'm just very out of the loop on it all and haven't done anything in ages and can't find an obvious example anywhere to work from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

insert checkbox:

[image]

try:

```
=IF(A1; IMAGE("https://i.stack.imgur.com/futhU.png"); 
        IMAGE("https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKel8.png"))
```

[image]

or:

```
=IMAGE("https://i.stack.imgur.com/"&IF(A1; "futhU"; "JKel8")&".png")
```

[image]

Comment: Additionally you could just store those images in another sheet and replace player0s IMAGE functions with the cell references to the desired images. Just a thought.